# Restricted user transparent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-theme, lockscreen

I wrote an app which starts an activity as a Dialog, with a "OK"-Button. If I press the button, the dialog should close.
My Android version is 4.3.

It works fine, if the user is the owner, but not if the user is a restricted user. The dialog disappears but the screen is still locked and with a grey overlay, like when a dialog is shown. So I can't do anything on the screen ecxept of pressing back and the home button. But the screen is still locked.

The restricted User has all rights.

When I install the app on the device, it's working fine, until I restart the device. Than the described Problem appears.

I have the same issue when I try to use a transparent activity. The Problem is here when I use `"<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>"`

Here my Code:

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>        
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>     
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>    
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
<style name="UserDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>

    <!--item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item-->
    <!--item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item-->
    <!--item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item-->
    <!-- item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item-->
    <!-- item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item-->
    <!-- item name="android:windowBackground">@color/trans</item-->
</style>
```

As you can see, I tried to override the animations. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802216/android-override-pending-transition-for-activity-theme-dialog-not-working) and also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565205/finish-activity-android-with-theme-dialog)
I can use "Theme.Transparent" or "UserDialog", both result to this error.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_testactivity"
        android:theme="@style/UserDialog">
</activity>
```

Activity:

```
public void OnClickButtonListener(){
        Button button_ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        button_ok.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {                    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            );
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);                    
startActivity(intent);  
finish();
```

Does anyone has an idea how to make this work?

Edit: The Problem occurs, if the dialog/transcular activity get started from an other activity or at startup via a broadcastreceiver. Also looks like it occurs if a service starts the activity.

Comment: Still don't have an idea why this occurs.
My workaround ist now, to have a black background. Doesn't look nice, but it works.